# paperclip background profile picture upload on s3 with partial processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, delayed-job, resque

I have user profile page in my application when user of an application can upload profile picture (Max size is 5MB). With the help of original image am generating three types of images and uploading them s3 using paperclip.

Now issue is, if user uploads an image of 5MB then it takes time to process and upload that image on s3. By the time user is waiting for image to get refreshed.

If I background this process then user might not see an uploaded image for some time. So he might not sure whether image is uploaded or not.

I was thinking to partially process image for users notification and then do rest of the image upload in background but not sure how we can do it.

Also if generation and uploading for single image for user usage might take time.

So what can I do in above case Or shall I keep profile images on server only instead of S3.

Comment: How about periodically backing up file in s3

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same thing.

One thing that might be useful is using [S3DirectUpload](https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload), although it is based on Carrierwave. It allows you to add progress bars, so that at least the user can see that the image is uploading, so they don't feel so bad.

The other option is to have a placeholder image that loads if the profile picture is not present (That way you can upload in the background).

```
user.profile_picture.present? ? user.profile_picture : some_placeholder_image
```

Comment: Actually I am processing image(generating thumbnail and others) at rails end and pushing them on S3. After this I am fetching S3 thumbnail image on users profile page.
I want to improve this, but above will not help in that case

Comment: Fair enough. I am sorry then I can't help. But it might be an idea to have a look through [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) documentation, as it supports a small preview as soon as the file is added.